# x64dbg "Use Graph command or menu action to draw control flow graph here..."

Tags: x64dbg

When I press "G" in the CPU view of the debugger I often get the following screen:

[image: Use Graph command or menu action to draw control flow graph here...]

In what cases can this error message happen? Obviously I can't yet give an exact way to reproduce it, I'm curios what to look for next time when I encounter such an issue. Is it from my side because I did not enable or did not care about something?

Do you also sometime encounter such a message?

Comment: I believe that you actual issue is the `Trace finished after 5000 steps` in the bottom left corner

Comment: Yes, it's finished, stopped somewhere and I wanted to check where I am in the current graph. Is that an invalid usecase? @macr0controller

Comment: Please report an issue with clear reproduction steps and the binary you used. When in the CPU view, pressing G should graph at your current selection.